# How to solve the Zipperdown Vulnerability issue on Cordova IOS?

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

**I've successfully created the Cordova iOS app, then I move into the production, but my app has been security
issue on**

```
Zipperdown Vulnerability leading to Remote Code Execution Attack
```

*How to solve  or resolve this issue?*

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, this vulnerability is used to gain access to the file system on the device and inject some malicious code for remote code execution.
How this works is,

Lets say you have an archive, Files inside this archive will have very common names such as cat.jpg, startup.sh, but sometimes they can have names like `../../abcd.sh`,
This type of file name, if we concatenate it with the destination directory (let's consider your destination directory `/var/www/webside/com.my.app/userFiles/`) will result in `/var/www/webside/abcd.sh`. Because `..` in scripting means previous directory, if you append this file name to directory 1, it will go 2 directories back, and so on.

Meaning abcd.sh file will directly go inside `/var/www/webside/` dir instead of user directory. This is called "dir traversal," and with this attack, you can gain access to your device's file system.
This might have a big impact if this replaces some important file in your mobile OS directory; it might compromise the OS or steal important data from the device.

**Solution:**
To fix this, you will need to validate each and every file when extracting it to destination folder,
One way would be to check for file names starting with "../.." You can ignore these files and discard them (don't write them in the destination); by doing this, your app will be saved from dir traversal.

```
for url in listOfFileUrlsInsideZip.allObjects {
    let path = (url as! NSURL).path!
    if path.contains("..") {
        continue
    }
}
```